# testing of jQuery in .php file on localhost and not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a login page where when I clicked on the input type="submit" [I'm a Student], I want to hide the div by slideDown effect and show another div by slideUp effect. I'm a little confident about my syntax at my jQuery but when I'm trying it at my localhost/folderName, sometimes it works but not showing effect and sometimes effect shows in a blink then back-to-normal(it's like only refreshing the page)

Here are my codes.

index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<div id="signInDiv">

    <h2 id="signInBanner">Sign In</h2>

    <form method="post">
        <table id="signInTableField">
            <tr><td><input id="signInField" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input id="signInField" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login" name="login"/></td></tr>
        </table>

        <hr id="horizontalLine">

        <h2 id="signUpBanner">Sign up here!</h2>

        <table id="accessTypeTableButtons">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="I'm a Student" class="studentRegisterButton" id="accessTypeButtons" name="studentType"/></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="I'm an Officer" class="officerRegisterButton" id="accessTypeButtons" name="officerType"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<!--Student Register Div-->

    <div id="studentRegisterDiv">

        <h2 id="studentSignUpBanner">Student Registration</h2>

            <form method="post" action="">
                <table id="registerStudentFields">
                    <tr><td><input id="studentField" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input id="studentField" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input id="studentField" type="text" name="studentnumber" placeholder="Student Number"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input id="studentField" type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input id="studentField" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input id="studentField" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input id="studentFieldButton" type="submit" name="submitStudent" value="Submit" />
                        <input id="studentFieldButton" type="submit" name="cncelStudentRegister" value="Cancel" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

layout.css :

```
/*------------Sign In Div------------*/
#signInDiv {
    background: white;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 65%;
}

table#signInTableField {
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

#signInBanner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 0px;
}

#signInTableField {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 50px;
    cellspacing: 10px;
}

#signInField {
    width: 275px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#loginButton {
    width: 280px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#horizontalLine {
    position: absolute;
    top: 210px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

table#accessTypeTableButtons {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

#accessTypeTableButtons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    left: 25px;
}

#signUpBanner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 210px;
}

#accessTypeButtons {
    width: 135px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

/*------------Student Register Div------------*/

#studentRegisterDiv {
    width: 350px;
    height: 470px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 65%;
    display: none;
}

#studentSignUpBanner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 30px;
}

table#registerStudentFields {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

#registerStudentFields {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 70px;
}

#studentField {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 275px;
    height: 35px;
}

#studentFieldButton {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 138px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

jquery.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".studentRegisterButton").click(function(){
        $("#signInDiv").slideDown(500);
        $("#studentRegisterDiv").slideUp(500);
    });

});
```

Sorry for the codings. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You have several duplicate IDs: signInField, accessTypeButtons. IDs must be unique. Use classes for things like this, not IDs.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your Student and Officer buttons have the same id, 'accessTypeButtons'.  Also your tags with the id's of 'signInField' is duplicated.  This is not allowed.  Change them to have unique id's.
2. Your Student and Officer buttons have a type of 'submit' and since these tags/buttons are inside of a form tag, it will postback to the server which might be the reason why you see the page refresh.  The jquery onclick event is fired first then the postback event is fired.  If you don't need to postback, change the type to 'button'

FYI...this is not a php specific issue.  It's a html and jQuery issue